# How to add a checkbox in SelectListActions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I need to add checkbox to Avengers, S.H.I.E.L.D., & Justice League & Superheroes & You Have Selected List

In this below demo code

jsfiddle.net/nzdak7aL/98

Comment: Welcome to SO. Did you already check the Help Center regarding asking questions with [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It's recommanded to post your problem code directly here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this into js

```
$('option').mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prop('selected', !$(this).prop('selected'));
    return false;
  });
```

and into css
option::

```
before {
  content: "\2610";
  width: 1.3em;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
option:checked::before {
  content: "\2611";
}
```

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/nzdak7aL/101/

Comment: how to do i  make it unselect on click in Avengers column

Comment: I hope you meant this

$('#PresenterList').click(function(e) {
   $('#StaffList option').each(function() {
     $(this).prop('selected', false);
    });
  });

Comment: Awesome how do i uncheck the items in superheroes section after adding to avenger sections any complete link will be appreciated

Comment: You can easily use this code. Just provide id of column to uncheck options $('#anyId option').each(function() { $(this).prop('selected', false); });

Answer (score 1):

Your request is unclear. Could you please add more details?

If I understand it correctly, you would like add checkboxes to the multi select field? This does not make any sense.

If you need custom styled checkboxes just do this:

```
<input id="checkbox-avenger" type="checkbox" name="something" value="Avengers" style="display: none;" />
<label for="checkbox-avenger">**here you custom layout stuff**</label>
```